# Gradle test task hangs forever on CountDownLatch

Tags: java, gradle

I was running gradle tests on different machines parallely from the same shared code using jenkins. But the gradle test task hangs forever. From the threadump I observed that main thread is waiting for to aquire some lock.
could anyone please suggest a solution/workaround?

Thread dump of test executor.

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1437.50ms elapsed=110.46s tid=0x0000020a6b317800 nid=0xeb4 waiting on condition  [0x00000015996fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000008233b800> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.4/LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(java.base@11.0.4/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(java.base@11.0.4/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1039)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(java.base@11.0.4/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1345)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(java.base@11.0.4/CountDownLatch.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:46)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:91)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:34)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:137)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:69)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:68)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:73)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 cpu=46.88ms elapsed=110.42s tid=0x0000020a7aa32800 nid=0x20b0 waiting on condition  [0x0000001599dfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@11.0.4/Reference.java:241)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@11.0.4/Reference.java:213)

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=110.42s tid=0x0000020a7b262000 nid=0xe78 in Object.wait()  [0x0000001599eff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - waiting on <no object reference available>
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000811c6000> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Finalizer.java:170)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=110.40s tid=0x0000020a7b2b7000 nid=0x150 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 cpu=187.50ms elapsed=110.40s tid=0x0000020a7b2b8000 nid=0x2014 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=55750.00ms elapsed=110.40s tid=0x0000020a7b2ba800 nid=0x1eb4 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C1 CompilerThread0" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=9015.63ms elapsed=110.40s tid=0x0000020a7b2c3000 nid=0x2d0 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"Sweeper thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=250.00ms elapsed=110.40s tid=0x0000020a7b2c4800 nid=0x1ca0 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Common-Cleaner" #10 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 cpu=15.63ms elapsed=110.10s tid=0x0000020a7b543000 nid=0xdac in Object.wait()  [0x000000159a4fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - waiting on <no object reference available>
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000811c6370> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@11.0.4/CleanerImpl.java:148)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)
        at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@11.0.4/InnocuousThread.java:134)

"Service Thread" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=109.25s tid=0x0000020a7dacc000 nid=0x1e4c runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Test worker" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=63062.50ms elapsed=108.92s tid=0x0000020a7e50d000 nid=0x1e54 runnable  [0x000000159abf8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(java.base@11.0.4/HashMap.java:339)
        at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(java.base@11.0.4/HashMap.java:510)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.<init>(java.base@11.0.4/LinkedHashMap.java:384)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(java.base@11.0.4/AnnotationParser.java:275)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(java.base@11.0.4/AnnotationParser.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(java.base@11.0.4/AnnotationParser.java:73)
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(java.base@11.0.4/Executable.java:604)
        - locked <0x000000008b03f940> (a java.lang.reflect.Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(java.base@11.0.4/Executable.java:602)
        - locked <0x000000008b03fa98> (a java.lang.reflect.Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotation(java.base@11.0.4/Executable.java:572)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(java.base@11.0.4/Method.java:695)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:118)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.4/Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"/127.0.0.1:65320 to /127.0.0.1:65318 workers Thread 2" #14 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=31.25ms elapsed=108.76s tid=0x0000020a7e023800 nid=0x4b8 waiting on condition  [0x000000159acfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000008233d130> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.4/LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.4/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.queue.EndPointQueue.take(EndPointQueue.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionDispatch.run(MessageHub.java:320)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"/127.0.0.1:65320 to /127.0.0.1:65318 workers Thread 3" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=15.63ms elapsed=108.76s tid=0x0000020a7c9e5000 nid=0xc34 runnable  [0x000000159adfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(java.base@11.0.4/WindowsSelectorImpl.java:339)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.4/WindowsSelectorImpl.java:167)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.4/SelectorImpl.java:124)
        - locked <0x000000008233bed0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x000000008233be48> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.4/SelectorImpl.java:141)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketInputStream.read(SocketConnection.java:185)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.fill(Input.java:146)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.require(Input.java:178)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.readByte(Input.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.serialize.kryo.KryoBackedDecoder.readByte(KryoBackedDecoder.java:81)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.InterHubMessageSerializer$MessageReader.read(InterHubMessageSerializer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:81)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$ConnectionReceive.run(MessageHub.java:268)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"Java2D Disposer" #16 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 cpu=31.25ms elapsed=107.09s tid=0x0000020a0f5a9800 nid=0x18d0 in Object.wait()  [0x000000159affe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - waiting on <no object reference available>
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x000000008259dc10> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.4/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(java.desktop@11.0.4/Disposer.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"AWT-Windows" #18 daemon prio=6 os_prio=0 cpu=78.13ms elapsed=107.09s tid=0x0000020a7dd50000 nid=0x1c24 runnable  [0x000000159b1ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(java.desktop@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(java.desktop@11.0.4/WToolkit.java:305)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"AWT-Shutdown" #21 prio=6 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=95.95s tid=0x0000020a0f167800 nid=0x184c in Object.wait()  [0x000000159a5ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x000000008259af90> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Object.java:328)
        at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(java.desktop@11.0.4/AWTAutoShutdown.java:291)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x000000008259af90> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"AWT-EventQueue-0" #25 prio=6 os_prio=0 cpu=15.63ms elapsed=95.34s tid=0x0000020a13199000 nid=0x129c waiting on condition  [0x000000159b4fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000082503fc8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.4/LockSupport.java:194)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@11.0.4/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(java.desktop@11.0.4/EventQueue.java:566)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(java.desktop@11.0.4/EventDispatchThread.java:190)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(java.desktop@11.0.4/EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(java.desktop@11.0.4/EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(java.desktop@11.0.4/EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(java.desktop@11.0.4/EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(java.desktop@11.0.4/EventDispatchThread.java:90)

"ClientMessageReceptor0" #26 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=91.73s tid=0x0000020a0f8f5800 nid=0x1570 runnable  [0x000000159b3fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at org.jacorb.orb.etf.StreamConnectionBase.read(StreamConnectionBase.java:111)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.getMessage(GIOPConnection.java:389)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessagesLoop(GIOPConnection.java:541)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessages(GIOPConnection.java:533)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.MessageReceptor.doWork(MessageReceptor.java:69)
        at org.jacorb.util.threadpool.ConsumerTie.run(ConsumerTie.java:60)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"ClientMessageReceptor1" #27 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=15.63ms elapsed=91.63s tid=0x0000020a0f8f6800 nid=0x19c0 runnable  [0x000000159b5fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at org.jacorb.orb.etf.StreamConnectionBase.read(StreamConnectionBase.java:111)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.getMessage(GIOPConnection.java:389)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessagesLoop(GIOPConnection.java:541)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.GIOPConnection.receiveMessages(GIOPConnection.java:533)
        at org.jacorb.orb.giop.MessageReceptor.doWork(MessageReceptor.java:69)
        at org.jacorb.util.threadpool.ConsumerTie.run(ConsumerTie.java:60)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"CacheQueueHandler" #28 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=91.33s tid=0x0000020a0f8f4000 nid=0x1f90 in Object.wait()  [0x000000159b6ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000835a6300> (a java.util.ArrayList)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Object.java:328)
        at chs.utility.dataservices.cache.FileBasedCache$RequestHandler.getNextRequest(FileBasedCache.java:474)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000835a6300> (a java.util.ArrayList)
        at chs.utility.dataservices.cache.FileBasedCache$RequestHandler.run(FileBasedCache.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"Ping Thread" #29 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=91.12s tid=0x0000020a0f8f7000 nid=0x2194 in Object.wait()  [0x000000159b8fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000835df190> (a java.lang.Object)
        at chs.utility.dataservices.SynchronizedObjectWaiter.waitOn(SynchronizedObjectWaiter.java:11)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000835df190> (a java.lang.Object)
        at chs.utility.dataservices.UserSessionWrapper$1.run(UserSessionWrapper.java:324)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #30 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=93.75ms elapsed=14.90s tid=0x0000020a7da37800 nid=0x2bec runnable  [0x00000015994fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.base@11.0.4/PlainSocketImpl.java:159)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(java.base@11.0.4/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(java.base@11.0.4/ServerSocket.java:551)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(java.base@11.0.4/ServerSocket.java:519)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(jdk.management.agent@11.0.4/LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(java.rmi@11.0.4/TCPTransport.java:394)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(java.rmi@11.0.4/TCPTransport.java:366)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)

"RMI TCP Connection(2)-10.103.19.231" #31 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=31.25ms elapsed=13.01s tid=0x0000020a7da35000 nid=0x11b8 runnable  [0x00000015993fc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(java.base@11.0.4/BufferedInputStream.java:252)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/BufferedInputStream.java:271)
        - locked <0x000000008763b7c8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.4/FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(java.rmi@11.0.4/TCPTransport.java:544)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(java.rmi@11.0.4/TCPTransport.java:796)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(java.rmi@11.0.4/TCPTransport.java:677)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$666/0x0000000101263c40.run(java.rmi@11.0.4/Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@11.0.4/Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(java.rmi@11.0.4/TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.4/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.4/Thread.java:834)
```

when the test ran in debug mode, the log file is filled with the below

```
2021-01-22T15:03:12.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:12.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:12.376+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:22.374+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:22.374+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:22.374+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:22.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:22.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:22.376+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:32.373+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:32.374+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:32.374+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:32.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:32.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:32.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:42.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:42.375+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:42.376+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:42.377+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:42.377+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:42.378+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:52.381+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:52.381+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:52.382+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-01-22T15:03:52.383+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
```

Gradle version: 6.3

```
gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.4 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.4+11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `gradlew --version`? Also, when you run the build with `--info --stackrace`, is there anything suspicious?

Comment: @thokuest added the gradle --version output in the question. I ran with --info --stacktrace, there is nothing suspicious. once the thread hangs its not printing anything.

Comment: All the test executors from different machines were writing to same jacoco.exec file, because of that when one executor is writing other executors are waiting. modified the code to use jacoco.exec per test executor and it resolved the issue.